# When listIterator is used as a reference type, the object assigned to it must implement it?

Tags: java, list, iterator, listiterator

For a reference variable whose type is an interface, object you assign to it must  implement the interface.
How does this stand true for the List Iterator interface which is being assigned an object which is of a class that does not implement it.(I couldn't find a relation in the hierarchy)

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

ListIterator<Type> it = list.listIterator(list.size());---1
```

I read about Iterator being the superclass of  ListIterator but i couldnt find a relation between ListIterator and ArrayList or List.

With `List` interface i know it has a method listIterator() which helps assign an iterator to collections. But which class actually implements the ListIterator for it to be assigned to it in the Hierarchy.

I'm trying to understand statement 1 and how its assigned this value.

Comment: If you have the JDK installed, and you're using Eclipse, you might be able to click on `ArrayList` and press F3 to see the source code for ArrayList. (Then look for the `listIterator` method)

Comment: Implementation classes don’t need to be `public`. And they are irrelevant. The method which returns the actual implementation tells you which behavior you can rely on.

Comment: @immibis I already did, I know about the method being there. I just want to know for Arraylist object to be assigned to the ListIterator interface type var, it is necessary for it to implement it or some higher class in hierarchy to implement it. How is this true for this code?

Comment: The `ArrayList` is **not** assigned to the `ListIterator` variable. The return value of the `listIterator(…)` method invocation will be assigned to it. That’s an entirely different object.

Comment: A class doesn't need a relationship to a object it returns. But considering the contract of `ListIterator` it's most likely a inner class.

Comment: For a reference variable whose type is an interface, object you assign to it must implement the interface.- Is it true for above statement

Comment: Of course, it’s true. But it’s unclear, what your problem is. You invoke a method which returns an object which has the required type and assign it to a variable of that type. There is nothing special to it. The list object is irrelevant.

Comment: @Holger I just want to know how it works thats all. Where's the implementation of the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of immibis comment, lets take a look at the implementation of listIterator(int):

```
public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index > size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: "+index);
    return new ListItr(index);
}
```

We see, the return type is `ListIterator<E>`, which is exactly what we would expect (as the ArrayList class definition is `public class ArrayList<E>`). For example, if we have an `ArrayList<String>`, the methods return type would be `ListIterator<String>`.

But what is this? It is not an `ListIterator` we create, but an instance of `ListItr`. Lets take a look a its definition:

```
private class ListItr extends Itr implements ListIterator<E>
```

Its an inner class of ArrayList, and it defines some class that implements the ListIterator-interface.

So, looking at your code we could add some brackets to make clearer what happens:

```
ListIterator<Type> it = (list.listIterator(list.size()));
```

What we do is taking our list, then calling `listIterator()` on that list, passing `list.size()` as argument. Then the method returns an ListIterator, which is assigned to `it`.

**EDIT:**

I'm not quite sure whether I understood your question right before. In this case, it is not ArrayList which has to implement the ListIterator interface, but the object which is returned by the `listIterator(int)` method you call **on an instance** of ArrayList, so it is only the object returned by that method call that has to implement the interface.

Comment: So basically the listIterator(int) method takes care of the implementation of the ListIterator Interface no matter what the collection implementation we're using?

Comment: @java_enthusiast: Each `List` implementation can have its own implementation of `listIterator(int)`, delivering its own `ListIterator` implementation. But subclasses of `AbstractList` inherit a [working implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#listIterator-int-) which they can use or override as they wish.

Comment: @java_enthusiast Look at the return statement: `return new ListItr(index);`
So basically it is the class ListItr which has to implement ListIterator, as it is returned from the method. And yes, the method takes care that the object it returns - `ListItr` - implements the interface (otherwise, the code would not compile).